# Admobs Banner not Displaying Libgdx

Tags: java, libgdx, admob

Hi all im trying to implement Admobs into my game but ive been stuck getting the banners to show for the last 2 days. My code is as follows.

```
public class MainActivity extends AndroidApplication {
private String adId = "ca-app-pub-3083731858905600/3602333561";
private String deviceId = "D117452E0EC02313A049B184D977046B";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    AndroidApplicationConfiguration cfg = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
    cfg.useGL20 = false;

    RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    getWindow().clearFlags(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
    View gameView = initializeForView(new FMGame(), cfg);

    AdView AdView = new AdView(this);
    AdView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
    AdView.setAdUnitId(adId); 

    AdRequest.Builder adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder();
    adRequest.addTestDevice(deviceId); 
    AdView.loadAd(adRequest.build());

    layout.addView(gameView);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams adParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    adParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
    adParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);

    layout.addView(AdView, adParams);

    setContentView(layout);

    initialize(new FMGame(), cfg);
}
}
```

My admob account says that my game is sending requests but the banner just won't show.

My logcat says the Ad is not visible since I have less than 10 reputation

Thanks

p.s ive been trawling this site for days and tried many different solutions please help....

Comment: you looked here? https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Google-Mobile-Ads-in-Libgdx-%28replaces-deprecated-AdMob%29 https://github.com/TheInvader360/tutorial-libgdx-google-ads/blob/9a4c9342d98c02e3c44e0b62fcfaa153d257130a/tutorial-libgdx-google-ads-android/src/com/theinvader360/tutorial/libgdx/google/ads/MainActivity.java

Comment: yes i have, but i double checked again and i forgot to delete the line initialize(new FMGame(), cfg); Thanks for your help